# Site Guest Users Cannot Insert or Query ContentDocument or ContentDocumentLink objects

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, guest-user

## Update (31/01/20)

As per the newly created [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352248&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), Salesforce has stated that in order to not receive an error while Inserting/Querying a ContentNote/ContentDocument/ContentDocumentLink as a Guest User on a Salesforce Site, you must use a Community.

---

As a Guest User on a Salesforce Site, executing Apex code to insert `ContentDocument` or `ContentDocumentLink` objects "silently fails".

I have configured a Site which has a simple landing page with the following 3 options available:

1. Insert `ContentDocument` (with a related `ContentDocumentLink` to an `Account`)
2. Query all `ContentDocuments`
3. Query all `ContentDocumentLinks` related to the `Account`

When I preview the Site as an Admin, all 3 options work successfully.

When accessing the Site as a Guest User, the DML operation for `ContentNote` insert silently fails (it states in debug log that 1 DML operation completed but `ContentNote` cannot be located by System Administrator), while the query options always return 0 records.

The page controller is as simple as can be, see below. Does anybody know why a Guest User would not be allowed to complete such actions?

```
public class CreateContentDocumentController {

    public void doInsert() {
        ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
        cn.put('Title', 'title');
        cn.put('Content', Blob.valueOf('body'));
        insert cn;

        // Account ID
        Id entityId = '0018A00000LzJob';

        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.put('LinkedEntityId', entityId);
        cdl.put('ContentDocumentId', cn.Id);
        cdl.put('ShareType', 'I');
        cdl.put('Visibility', 'AllUsers');
        insert cdl;       
    }

    public Integer mapSize {get; set;}

    public void doQuery() {     
        // Account ID
        Id entityId = '0018A00000LzJob';

        Map<Id, ContentDocumentLink> linksMap = new Map<Id, ContentDocumentLink>([
                select Id, ContentDocument.Id, ContentDocument.FileType, LinkedEntityId
                from ContentDocumentLink
                where LinkedEntityId = :entityId]);

        mapSize = linksMap.size();   
    }
}
```

Comment: A Summer '19 [change](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003UK7QAM&title=soql-on-contentversion-returns-results-even-if-the-site-guest-user-does-not-have-access-to-the-record) may have introduced this.

Comment: Try without sharing...

Comment: @CasparHarmer makes no difference. This is a Salesforce issue and I will be providing a POC to their support team, which we hope will go to their Product team.

Comment: It's likely by design, unfortunately. One technique I have implemented that works is to fire a platform event -> handle that event by performing search -> fire "results" platform event and handle that in your community. Unfortunately, this will require a custom version of the empAPI, as it is currently not supported in communties.