# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You don't have permission to share this file.: [ContentDocumentId]

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, file-sharing

I am Facing this issue only while executing the below code in the Guest User context, how to resolve it?

The exeption occurs while inserting contentDocumentLink Record.

```
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.title = filename; 
        cv.versionData = test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('test body') : contentBody;
        cv.pathonclient = '/'+filename;
        cv.FirstPublishLocationId = [select isSandbox from Organization].isSandbox ? '0050l000003ertXAAQ' : '05898000045xtVAAQ';
        cv.SharingOption = 'A';
        insert cv;

        // create a new contentdocumentlink record to link the file to an record
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.contentdocumentid = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :cv.Id].ContentDocumentId;
        cdl.linkedentityid = recordid; // set to the id of the record
        cdl.sharetype = 'v'; // set the sharing access to viewer
        cdl.visibility = 'allusers'; // set the visibility to all users in the organization
        insert cdl;
```

Comment: See [Idea- Site Guest User should be able to access Content](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcM1UAJ/site-guest-user-should-be-able-to-access-content) , [Prev SSE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286109/site-guest-users-cannot-insert-or-query-contentdocument-or-contentdocumentlink-o)